# Echo a string containing a variable, with spaces at both ends?

Tags: bash, shell, echo

How would I echo a string containing a variable, that has a lot of spaces before and after the var?

**Desired output is:**

```
|                        BLAH v1.2.3                          |
```

The `$v` var is fine, and contains the proper value.

**Here's what I have so far:**

```
#!/bin/bash

v=$(cat version.json)

echo '|                        BLAH v${v}                          |'
```

**Update (see comments):**

```
#!/bin/bash

v="$(cat version.json)"

echo "|                        BLAH v${v}                          |"
```

**Results in:**

[image]

Notice:

- how the front space shows up before the front pipe
- the pipe bumps up next to the first word
- the first 2 letters have vanished into the ether (lol)
- and (cant tell for sure where the last spaces are there) but the last pipe ended up on the next line.

Comment: If you want interpolation, use `"` instead of `'`.

Comment: Sidenote: Do `v="$(cat version.json)"`

Comment: If for some bizarre reason you want single quotes, you could do `echo '|            '${v}'              
            |'`, but even then best practice would be to do `echo '|        '"${v}"'          |'`, but...you probably just want to put the whole thing in double-quotes.

Comment: @TedLyngmo and @.William Pursell, unfortunately still no luck. I added what happened in the update in the OP. I also tried pasting verbatim both of William's suggestions (no luck), and adding double quotes around the var in the echo, like this `"${v}"`, but same result.

Comment: It looks like `version.json` has DOS line endings. See: [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)